# IE7 compatibility mode does not work in DNN 5.6

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, dotnetnuke

IE7 compatibility mode does not work in DNN 5.6

How do i get this meta-tag to work, so that IE9 runs as browser mode IE7 compatibility and document mode IE7?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is having full detail about this topic. Also there is another [blog entry here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that says, "It seems like the X-UA-Compatible tag has to be the first tag in the  section."